# Methods to speed up arthimetic using calculus

Tags: calculus

We know that we can approximate roots by approximating after first order terms of the Taylor series, but is there a way to speed up arithmetic by hand using calculus?

An attempt at this was through the method of differentials, say I am tasked with computing:

$$ \frac{89.2}{35.432}$$

I could think of the above using:

$$ f(x,y)  = \frac{x}{y}$$

And the associated finite change

$$ \Delta f =  (\frac{\Delta x}{x} - \frac{\Delta y}{y})f(x,y)$$

So, doing a linear approximation of $f(x,y)$ about $ \frac{90}{30}$, by the formula:

$$ f(90,30) + f(90,30) \left( \frac{\Delta x}{90} - \frac{\Delta y}{30} \right)$$

$$ \frac{90}{30} + \frac{90}{30} ( \frac{-.8}{90} - \frac{5.432}{35.432}) \approx 3 \left[ 1 -\frac{1}{7} \right]= 3 \times (.85)= 2.55 $$

The real answer was 2.517 (by calculator) , so I got less than 2% error.

What other ways are there of approximating multiplication and division other than using differentials? / What are things to keep in mind  to get better approximation? (Like choosing what terms to neglect)

Ideally, I wish to have <1% error.

---

[Reference for the differential approximation I used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkRlB8PwD94)

Comment: That seems like more operations than just doing the division.

Comment: That's cause I wrote out all the steps explicitly , if you do it without, it is faster than dividing

Comment: For your example, I would have chosen the approximation $90/36=15/6=5/2$.

Comment: That is a good idea

Comment: In fact [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Multiplicative_inverses_of_numbers_and_power_series) is used in high-precision division (thousands of digits, say) combined with fast multiplication methods; there's also a Newtonian method for computing square roots, etc.

Comment: This method seems a cat that tries to catch his tail. Trying to simplifying $\frac{89.2}{35.432}$ you get some steps later $\frac{5.432}{35.432}$, that is as "difficult" as the first one to my eyes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gabrielek $ \frac{5.432}{35.432} \approx \frac{1}{7}$, one more approximation is used

Comment: If you use that approximation then the one provided by @mathcounterexample.net is better and needs no additional arguments